# PHPExcel: showing header & footer not only in printing preview

Tags: header, footer, phpexcel

I am generating excel document via PHPExcel library, I've set the header & footer sections. But when I open the document I dont see header neither footer. The header & footer is shown when viewing print preview. Also when I insert header & footer via menu, I can see my header & footer values I've set in PHPExcel.

Does anyone now how to show header & footer by default?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from Excel Help:

> You can add headers or footers at the top or bottom of a printed
> worksheet. For example, you might create a footer that has page
> numbers, the date and time, and the name of your file.
>
> Headers and
> footers are not displayed on the worksheet in Normal view — they are
> displayed only in Page Layout view and on the printed pages. You can
> insert headers or footers in Page Layout view where you can see them,
> or you can use the Page Setup dialog box if you want to insert headers
> or footers for more than one worksheet at the same time. For other
> sheet types, such as chart sheets, you can insert headers and footers
> only by using the Page Setup dialog box.

So I would not expect MS Excel to show headers & footers by default